# SQL só em post personalizado do WordPress para conversão de tags

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, html-tags, taxonomia

Digamos que um site usando WordPress tem metade dos posts do tipo padrão, e a outra metade usando um Tipo de Post Personalizado "review" http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Tipos_de_Posts_Personalizados.

Mas esse tipo de post não tinha tags registradas, então compartilhava as dos posts padrão (post_tag).

Depois a tag personalizada é designada aos posts personalizados, então ele passa a usar "review-tag". Como posso via SQL converter as tags padrão só dentro desses posts personalizados para o novo tipo?

Esse comando, por exemplo, converte TODAS as tags:

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET taxonomy='review-tag', parent=0 WHERE taxonomy='tag';
```

Mas preciso fazer isso só com os posts do tipo review.

Answer (score 1):

De uma olhada no link abaixo para entender o relacionamento entre as tabelas:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Voce precisa fazer um join das tabelas wp_posts com wp_term_relationships e entao com a tabela wp_term_taxonomy para conseguir filtrar pelo post_type = "review" e saber quais taxonomies alterar.

De qualquer maneira, acredito que sera mais simples, e menos arriscado, realizar essa alteração pelo proprio wp-admin.